# error: expected primay-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda, cuando quiero correr el código, me manda este error. Trabajo en Zinjal con C++, pues soy principiante, acá está el código. No entiendo mucho el error. Básicamente se trata de crear un programa, que al digitar un número, muestre sus divisores, ya sea entre 2, 3 y 5. Eso sería todo, muchas gracias colegas. El error está en el if casi al final, y el error dice: error: expected 
primary-expression before '.' token en todos los últimos if, no sé que hacer y el trabajo debo entregarlo mañana, muchas gracias.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Numero 
    {
    private:
        int numero;
    public:
        Numero()
        {
            numero=0;   }

        Numero(int num)
        {
            numero=num; }

        void setNumero(int num)
        {
            numero=num; }

        int getNumero()
        {
            return numero;  }


        bool divDos()
        {
            int ultimoNumero= numero%10;

            if (ultimoNumero==0 ||ultimoNumero==2 || ultimoNumero==4 ||ultimoNumero==6 ||ultimoNumero==8)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        bool divCinco()
        {
            int ultimoNumero= numero%10;

            if (ultimoNumero==0 ||ultimoNumero==5) 
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        bool divTres()
        {
            int suma=0;
            int num=numero;  //se copia en una variable local para no perder el valor original

            while (num!=0) // separa los digitos y los suma
            {
                suma+=num%10;
                num=num/10;     
            }
            if( (suma%3)==0 )
                   return true;
            else
                return false; }
    };
    int main()
    {   
        int num=0;
        char resp='s';
        while (resp == 's' || resp == 'S')
        {

            if(Numero.divDos)
                cout<<"\nEs Divisible entre 2\n";
            if(Numero.divTres)
                cout<<"\nEs Divisible entre 3\n";
            if(Numero.divCinco)
                cout<<"\nEs Divisible entre 5\n";

            cout<<endl<<"Desea continuar? Digite S o N" <<endl<<endl;
            cin>> resp;
        }

        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: yo tengo una duda similar si la pudieran responder les agradeceria muchisimo, colegas del oficio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes crear una variable del tipo "Numero" y con esta poder acceder a los métodos, también las comparaciones que haces en los IF devuelven valores tipo bool, las cuales deberias comparar con "==".
Deberia funcionar así:

```
int main()
{   
    Numero nr;
    int num=0;
    char resp='s';

    while (resp == 's' || resp == 'S')
    {

        if(nr.divDos()== true)
            cout<<"\nEs Divisible entre 2\n";
        if(nr.divTres()==true)
            cout<<"\nEs Divisible entre 3\n";
        if(nr.divCinco()==true)
            cout<<"\nEs Divisible entre 5\n";

        cout<<endl<<"Desea continuar? Digite S o N" <<endl<<endl;
        cin>> resp;
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!